# Return one unique custom post type result when it shares a custom taxonomy in WP_QUERY?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query

Is it possible to remove custom post types from WP_QUERY that have a same shared custom taxonomy so that only one custom post type associated to that custom taxonomy is returned?

Example: Get an Items custom post type, returning only one Item per a custom taxonomy.

On a taxonomy-types.php page, I'm using WP_QUERY to get the Items custom post type. Then, wp_get_object_terms to get the Models custom taxonomy for the Items, and displayed that. However, I can end up with duplicate Models displayed because WP_QUERY is returning all Items and not one Item per unique Model.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you post your actual `WP_Query()` code?

Comment: Thanks guys. I think I may have found a solution.

What I did:

-On taxonomy-types.php, get all Items for that type using WP_QUERY.
-Loop through them, use get_the_terms() to get taxonomy Model for each Item
-Still in the loop: use PHP's in_array() function and a $model_ids array for unique Model checking
-Still in the loop: if the Model is unique, store the Item id in an $item_ids array
-End that loop
-Use WP_QUERY to get Items with 'post__in' set to the $item_ids array

Comment: Can you please post that as an **answer**. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys. I think I may have found a solution.

What I did:

- On `taxonomy-types.php`, get all Items for that type using WP_QUERY.
- Loop through them, use `get_the_terms()` to get taxonomy Model for each Item
- Still in the loop: use PHP's `in_array()` function and a `$model_ids` array for unique Model checking
- Still in the loop: if the Model is unique, store the Item id in an `$item_ids` array
- End that loop
- Use WP_QUERY to get Items with `'post__in'` set to the `$item_ids` array

Comment: Some code would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, when you register a CP on your theme, there is an option "exclude_from_search" set it to false and it won't show on search results.

For more information check: [Register Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)